# DialogFlow Voice based search on application database (iOS & Android)

Tags: android, ios, dialogflow-es

I have looked the DialogFlow documentation but I am unable to find how can I give voice search functionality so that records can be filtered fast.

Is there any way DialogFlow allow this kind of functionality?

Suppose, I give command using voice like "search order xxxx" then I need to filter my datalist having order xxxx.

Is it possible with DialogFlow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are samples for using Dialogflow in [iOS](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-apple-client) and [Android](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client), which will show you how to get started with streaming audio and getting back structured results.